# JNI table overflow in android app

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, java-native-interface, out-of-memory

I have an android app that goes back and forth between a couple of screens organized as fragments of an activity that uses a viewPager to make scrolling possible.

When moving too much within these screens the app crashes with an 
JNI ERROR (app bug): local reference table overflow (max=512)

here is the stacktrace:

```
03-23 13:25:56.781 8120-8506/com.example.debug A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:127] JNI ERROR (app bug): local reference table overflow (max=512)
03-23 13:25:56.781 8120-8506/com.example.debug A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:127] local reference table dump:
03-23 13:25:56.781 8120-8506/com.example.debug A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:127]   Last 10 entries (of 512):
03-23 13:25:56.781 8120-8506/com.example.debug A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:127]       511: 0x144abc00 long[] (6 elements)
03-23 13:25:56.781 8120-8506/com.example.debug A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:127]       510: 0x144abbc0 long[] (6 elements)
03-23 13:25:56.781 8120-8506/com.example.debug A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:127]       509: 0x144abb80 long[] (6 elements)
03-23 13:25:56.781 8120-8506/com.example.debug A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:127]       508: 0x144abb40 long[] (6 elements)
03-23 13:25:56.781 8120-8506/com.example.debug A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:127]       507: 0x144abb00 long[] (6 elements)
03-23 13:25:56.781 8120-8506/de.everskill.everskill.debug A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:127]       506: 0x144abac0 long[] (6 elements)
03-23 13:25:56.781 8120-8506/de.everskill.everskill.debug A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:127]       505: 0x144aba80 long[] (6 elements)
03-23 13:25:56.781 8120-8506/de.everskill.everskill.debug A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:127]       504: 0x144aba40 long[] (6 elements)
03-23 13:25:56.781 8120-8506/de.everskill.everskill.debug A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:127]       503: 0x144aba00 long[] (6 elements)
03-23 13:25:56.781 8120-8506/de.everskill.everskill.debug A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:127]       502: 0x144ab9c0 long[] (6 elements)
03-23 13:25:56.781 8120-8506/de.everskill.everskill.debug A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:127]   Summary:
03-23 13:25:56.781 8120-8506/de.everskill.everskill.debug A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:127]       511 of long[] (6 elements) (511 unique instances)
03-23 13:25:56.781 8120-8506/de.everskill.everskill.debug A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:127]         1 of java.lang.Thread
03-23 13:25:56.781 8120-8506/de.everskill.everskill.debug A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:127] 
03-23 13:25:56.781 3493-3573/? D/StatusBarManagerService: manageDisableList userId=0 what=0x0 pkg=Window{5a171b1 u0 d0 Starting de.everskill.everskill.debug}
03-23 13:25:56.791 3035-3035/? D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0x7fff60dac8
03-23 13:25:56.791 1976-1976/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
03-23 13:25:56.791 1976-1976/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'samsung/zerofltexx/zeroflte:6.0.1/MMB29K/G920FXXU5DQA7:user/release-keys'
03-23 13:25:56.791 1976-1976/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '11'
03-23 13:25:56.791 1976-1976/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
03-23 13:25:56.791 1976-1976/? A/DEBUG: pid: 8120, tid: 8699, name: pool-2-thread-1  >>> de.everskill.everskill.debug <<<
03-23 13:25:56.791 1976-1976/? A/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
03-23 13:25:56.811 1976-1976/? A/DEBUG: Abort message: 'art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:127] JNI ERROR (app bug): local reference table overflow (max=512)'
03-23 13:25:56.811 1976-1976/? A/DEBUG:     x0   0000000000000000  x1   00000000000021fb  x2   0000000000000006  x3   0000000000000000
03-23 13:25:56.811 1976-1976/? A/DEBUG:     x4   0000000000000000  x5   0000000000000001  x6   0000000000000000  x7   0000000000000000
03-23 13:25:56.811 1976-1976/? A/DEBUG:     x8   0000000000000083  x9   0000000000016240  x10  000000000057d960  x11  000000000057daa0
03-23 13:25:56.811 1976-1976/? A/DEBUG:     x12  0000000000000000  x13  0000007f960f5000  x14  0000000000000000  x15  0000007f960e7000
03-23 13:25:56.811 1976-1976/? A/DEBUG:     x16  0000007f960e7568  x17  0000007f9607a338  x18  0000000000000000  x19  0000007f59dff500
03-23 13:25:56.811 1976-1976/? A/DEBUG:     x20  0000007f59dff440  x21  0000000000000011  x22  0000000000000006  x23  0000007f64056240
03-23 13:25:56.811 1976-1976/? A/DEBUG:     x24  0000007f9236cbc0  x25  0000007f78ac5200  x26  0000007f92475bc0  x27  0000000000000001
03-23 13:25:56.811 1976-1976/? A/DEBUG:     x28  0000007f64056100  x29  0000007f59dfe8b0  x30  0000007f96077ad4
03-23 13:25:56.811 1976-1976/? A/DEBUG:     sp   0000007f59dfe8b0  pc   0000007f9607a340  pstate 0000000020000000
03-23 13:25:56.821 1976-1976/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
03-23 13:25:56.821 1976-1976/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 0000000000069340  /system/lib64/libc.so (tgkill+8)
03-23 13:25:56.821 1976-1976/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 0000000000066ad0  /system/lib64/libc.so (pthread_kill+68)
03-23 13:25:56.821 1976-1976/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 0000000000023910  /system/lib64/libc.so (raise+28)
03-23 13:25:56.821 1976-1976/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 000000000001e240  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+60)
03-23 13:25:56.821 1976-1976/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 0000000000430e38  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEv+304)
03-23 13:25:56.821 1976-1976/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 00000000001373a4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD2Ev+3136)
03-23 13:25:56.821 1976-1976/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 0000000000272f88  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art22IndirectReferenceTable3AddEjPNS_6mirror6ObjectE+372)
03-23 13:25:56.821 1976-1976/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 000000000035bff0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art3JNI21GetObjectArrayElementEP7_JNIEnvP13_jobjectArrayi+472)
03-23 13:25:56.821 1976-1976/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 0000000000156ee0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI21GetObjectArrayElementEP7_JNIEnvP13_jobjectArrayi+524)
03-23 13:25:56.821 1976-1976/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 0000000000052ef4  /data/app/de.everskill.everskill.debug-3/lib/arm64/librealm-jni.so (Java_io_realm_internal_TableQuery_nativeBatchUpdateQueries+616)
03-23 13:25:56.821 1976-1976/? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 00000000018e6d40  /data/app/de.everskill.everskill.debug-3/oat/arm64/base.odex (offset 0xddf000) (long[] io.realm.internal.TableQuery.nativeBatchUpdateQueries(long, long[], long[][], long[][], boolean[][])+244)
03-23 13:25:56.821 1976-1976/? A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 0000000001903578  /data/app/de.everskill.everskill.debug-3/oat/arm64/base.odex (offset 0xddf000) (void io.realm.internal.async.QueryUpdateTask.run()+588)
03-23 13:25:56.821 1976-1976/? A/DEBUG:     #12 pc 0000000001900748  /data/app/de.everskill.everskill.debug-3/oat/arm64/base.odex (offset 0xddf000) (void io.realm.internal.async.BgPriorityRunnable.run()+140)
03-23 13:25:56.821 1976-1976/? A/DEBUG:     #13 pc 0000000003492ec0  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (offset 0x2f48000)
```

What I got from googleing is that I am basically not cleaning up the memory I allocate and since I never leave the activity it is not done by the garbage collector automatically.

So I need to manullay release the allocated memory. But can you hint me towards anything on what to look for?
What kind of elements do allocate memory in this JNI Table?
And what is the JNI table?
How do I free memory in the table?

Thanks a lot guys!
Best
TobHo

Comment: Is the actual JNI code your own, or from some other library?

Comment: not mine. I am not calling any JNI methods myself. I am using realm. They might be using JNI since as far as I know the core is written in C++?

Comment: You are creating java long[6] array on c++ but not releasing it. You need to release the array when not needed anymore by calling `ReleaseLongArrayElements`

Comment: problem is I am not doing this myself. I have no C++ code that I wrote. which means it is probably a library I am using. I will investigate further and see if I can find out which one.

Comment: I am happy for every hint on how to do that though :P